# How to modify Mediawiki Login form

Tags: forms, authentication, attributes, mediawiki

I'm trying to add the attribute `autocomplete="off"` in mediawiki login form. Being completely new, I'm unable to find where the form is being built.

I'm using MediaWiki 1.29.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Things I did to find it:
 1. Added the following code in LocalSettings.php

```
$wgHooks['UserLoginForm'][] = 'modifyLoginForm';
function modifyLoginForm( &$template ) {
   //Printed template and got the following
   /*

 UserloginTemplate Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [link] => 
            [header] => 
            [name] => Admin
            [password] => 
            [retype] => 
            [email] => 
            [realname] => 
            [domain] => 
            [reason] => 
            [action] => /mediawiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&action=submitlogin&type=login&returnto=Main+Page
            [message] => 
            [messagetype] => error
            [createemail] => 
            [userealname] => 1
            [useemail] => 1
            [emailrequired] => 
            [emailothers] => 1
            [canreset] => 1
            [resetlink] => 1
            [canremember] => 1
            [usereason] => 
            [remember] => 
            [cansecurelogin] => 
            [stickHTTPS] => 
            [token] => 18955182baa69e0a66edefghi4e0ef
            [loginend] => 
            [signupend] => 
            [usedomain] => 
        )
*/
}
```

2. Tried to modify includes/templates/Userlogin.php . There is a login form, but it didn't get affected.
3. Checked LoginSignupSpecialPage.php, but not sure how to add the attribute.

Comment: Googling UserLoginForm should take you to its [manual page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/UserLoginForm) which tells you it's deprecated and what hook to use instead. (How do you even have `includes/templates/Userlogin.php`? That file should not exist in 1.29.)

Comment: This happened after an upgrade from an older version